# Fantasy series where each book takes place on a different world that overly expressed a certain element?

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

From what I remember their was a war between two different groups of people. The winners put the losers in a labyrinth that was constantly trying to kill them (although I think that was a mistake). One of the labyrinth people escapes and by orders goes to each individual world to reestablish a connection network(?). One the first one he comes across a crazy old man who fails a lot, who turns out to be one of the peoples who entrapped the labyrinth people. One world is nothing but forests that has elves and humans, another is and underground world where the people there bring back the dead, and another is nothing but oceans where their is a race of ultimate evil dragon/snake/eel things. What is the name of this series?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That sounds like the [Death Gate Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_Gate_Cycle).